# Oracle SQL Developer - way to add comma to the end of each line for all items in the IN clause

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can't be the only person who has run into this, but I have not been able to find anything regarding this question.  I'm hoping there is a simple solution that I just haven't come across.  What I would like to have is a way in SQL Developer to simply append a comma to a selection of lines, so a statement like this:

```
select * from orders where order_number in (
10000
10001
10002
10003
)
```

Would turn into this:

```
select * from orders where order_number in (
10000,
10001,
10002,
10003
)
```

The comma can be at the beginning or end of the line as long as it is valid syntax.  Is there a plugin or something I can click on (after making a text selection, maybe?) that will automatically do this?  I am having to copy data to Excel and concatenate a comma to my lists and then copy them back to SQL Developer at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of SQL Developer supports regex find and replace, then you can try the following from the find dialog (with the regex checkbox selected):

**Find:**

```
^([0-9])+$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1,
```

This should hit every line which has a solitary number on it (i.e. what you seem to want to target), and replace it with itself followed by a single comma.  Note that I don't have SQL Developer in front of me; I've assumed the first capture group is accessible with `$1`, but it could be `\1` or `\\1` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have tag: visual-studio. In case you work with visual vs SQL Developer, I usually do it by follow this step.

1. copy to visual.
2. Keep Alt + left and move mouse from top to bottom.
3. Pus comma "," to line
4. Copy it to SQL Developer again.

[image]

The second way, I can do it by: Ctr + Find, and replace 1000 by ,1000

Answer (score 0):

Edit > Block Selection

Then click and drag (or shift + down/up arrow) to create a multi-line cursor.